# how to name the app iPad version

Tags: app-store

This question is not a tech question.
I have an iPhone app name 'abc', I will release a version for iPad.
How to name it
I check on app store found that some people name

abc HD

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Comment: If it isn't a programming question, you _know_ it doesn't belong here. Why even ask? It _may_ be more appropriate on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start uploading process of your application on store and you will get error message  if application name already exists something like this:

> The Application Name that you provided
>   has already been used. Please provide
>   a unique Application Name.

- [AppStore: Stake your claim](http://carpeaqua.com/2009/04/11/appstore-stake-your-claim/)

Answer (score 0):

Off topic though it is, if you're going the separate app (rather than universal binary) route, then it's common to use "HD" to differentiate between the versions.